# How would you configure multiple configurations of Spring Cloud's SQS Message Listener Containers?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

We have a use case wherein some of our listeners would need to have a different message executor thread count. Or rather some queue listeners would need to have less concurrent message processing than the other queue listeners.

Upon studying the code, the QueueMessageHandler looks for all the SQSListener annotated methods, and configure them all with the same attributes. This includes the max message per batch config which we would like to vary per listener.

Do we need to customize QueueMessageHandler, or is there a more proper way to do this?